# How can I generate ConfigMap from directory without create it?

Tags: kubernetes

How can I generate ConfigMap from directory without create it?

If I use:

```
$ kubectl create configmap my-config --from-file=configuration/ -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
   data:
...
```

ConfigMap yaml output is displayed but `my-config` is created on current Kubernetes project context.

I would like only generate ConfigMap file, it is possible? Are there a `kubectl create` "dry" mode?

Best regards,
Stéphane

Answer (score 19):

Just add `--dry-run` so:

```
$ kubectl create configmap my-config --from-file=configuration/ -o yaml --dry-run
```

Source: https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/kubectl/kubectl_create_configmap/

Answer (score 1):

2023 UPDATE, (it's an old question but google search for creating configmap dry-run is pointing here)

```
kubectl create configmap my-config --from-file=./my-config.json --dry-run=client -o yaml > local-config.yaml
```

The change is in the dry-run option, need to be --dry-run=client|server
-o is for output, in YAML in this case.

The last part "> local-config.yaml" is to get the YAML output of the create command into a file (to be applied later with kubectl apply -f)

doc: https://kubenetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands
a